Firebase timestamps with Typescript
I'm trying to figure out the nightmare of dates with Firebase.
I declare my objects with types as follows:
export type FirebaseTimestamp = { _seconds: number, _nanoseconds: number } 

type MyObject = {
createdAt: FirebaseTimestamp
}

These type configs are used both by my frontend (NextJS) and Cloud Functions from Firebase.
Please note, that all objects I retrieve from firestore I convert to my type with the following:
const fetch = firestore.col().get()
const myObject: MyObject = {
id: fetch.id,
...fetch.data(),
}

If I change the FirebaseTimestamp to any of the following like suggested by other questions:
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"
type FirebaseTimestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp

It doesn't work because the Firestore value is a number, not a function, so doesn't work when I retrieve it from Firestore.
If I do it with the SDK
import {firestore} from "firestore"
type FirebaseTimestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp

Same problem along with my backend complaining that it doesn't know the library.
How can I type cast the timestamps? And how do I generate them both in the frontend using SDK and backend cloud functions?
const createdAt = ....???
// And how to convert it to a JS date
const displayDate = new Date(createdAd).toString()

In my cloud functions
const createdAt = ....????

And my type declaration
type MyObj = { createdAt: ... ????? }


The Timestamp type is correctly imported for the most modern web SDK like this:
import { Timestamp } from "firebase/firestore"

And for the most modern Firebase Admin like this:
import { Timestamp } from "firebase-admin/firestore"

If you examine their declarations, they do not have the exact same definition and cannot be used interchangeably.  They can only be used when immediately reading a document.  If you need them to be serialized and sent elsewhere, you should pick out the seconds and nanos values explicitly (using the type's public API and not by digging into implementation details) for custom serialization, and then use the appropriate SDK's Timestamp constructor to reconstitute a new Timestamp after deserialization.
If you need a custom definition that can work somewhat between both FE and BE, you can try this:
export type TimestampLike = {
    readonly seconds: number
    readonly nanoseconds: number
    toDate(): Date
    toMillis(): number
    isEqual(other: TimestampLike): boolean
    valueOf(): string
}


Thanks @Doug, maybe I phrased the question wrong. But how do I declare a date type in this case then? I don't want to have different typescript files declaration for my frontend and backend. Ideally it would just be stored as a new Date().toString() but then the sorting doesn't work with Firestore.

Such as, in my frontend I can do:
const createdAt = ....?

In my cloud functions
const createdAt = ....?

And my type declaration
type MyObj = { createdAt: ... ? 


I've tried to clarify the question by updating the end.

You can't share the same definition between frontend and backend - as I said, they are not interchangeable.  They just don't have the same shape.  The best you can do is create a new type that shares enough in common between FE and BE.
